# I cannot add node links to primary links

Tags: 6, navigation

I have a problem that is driving me crazy. I've been trying to solve it for a week now without luck.
The problem is, I can't add any internal (node/xxx) links to primary-links. After I add one, it appears, but I cannot edit or add any nodes until I delete that menu item. If I try to edit a node, i get the message **"username admin does not exist"**. It looks like this triggers an effect that is causing admin user to lose permisson for node_access. After I delete the created menu item, everything is back to normal... until I add another menu item.

Here's a summary:

- I can add external links to primary-links, no problem
- I can add internal links to seconday-links, no problem
- It doesn't matter if I add the menu item manually or by specifying one on the node edit page, the effect is the same
- The language, weight and position of the menu item doesn't matter, as long as I add an *internal* link to primary-links, the above problem appears
- I tried to rebuild the menu, disable modules, clear the cache, rebuild permissions, no luck
- I double checked the menu_links table, there were some orphan items (had no parents) which I deleted, but otherwise everything is fine

I am using Drupal 6.19 with only one user (the admin), a bunch of modules and 11 languages. I **must** solve this problem soon as we need to add another language and it'll definately need some internal links in the menu.

Edit: Here are the modules currently enabled:

CCK

- Content   6.x-2.8
- Content Copy  6.x-2.8
- FileField 6.x-3.7
- FileField Sources 6.x-1.2
- Node Reference    6.x-2.8
- Number    6.x-2.8
- Option Widgets    6.x-2.8
- Text  6.x-2.8

Location

- IP to Locale  6.x-1.0-rc1
- Smart IP  6.x-1.3

Meta tags

- Nodewords 6.x-1.11
- Nodewords - basic meta tags   6.x-1.11

Multilanguage

- Block translation 6.x-1.7
- CCK translation   6.x-1.7
- Content type translation  6.x-1.7
- Internationalization  6.x-1.7
- Menu translation  6.x-1.7
- String translation    6.x-1.7

Other

- Custom Page   6.x-1.17
- Custom Page Admin UI  6.x-1.17
- GeoIP 6.x-1.4
- Global Redirect   6.x-1.2
- Menu attributes   6.x-2.0-beta1
- Menu breadcrumb   6.x-1.3
- Page Title    6.x-2.3
- Path redirect 6.x-1.0-rc2
- Token 6.x-1.15
- Webform   6.x-3.14

I can provide any information if you can help, just ask!

Thanks in advance

Comment: In order to get reasonable answers here you are going to need to provide a list of contrib modules installed, and possibly their versions. Also, any particular reason why you are on a really old version of Drupal 6 (it came out over 2 years ago)? If core is that far out of date, I shudder to think how far contrib is behind.

Comment: I know that 6.19 is very old, but I have a lot of tasks beside maintaining the site, and the company has an unwritten "if it's working, don't mess with it" policy.
I will try to update the site, but I don't want to break it as I only have FTP and PHPMyadmin access to the server, nothing more. I can't rebuild the database myself in case of a failure.
I inserted the moduls I use into the original question.

Comment: Well clearly this falls into the "broken" category, adding items to the menu is a fairly core piece of functionality. I would suggest rebuilding the site locally, updating core and *all* the contrib, and then attempting to re-ask this question. At the moment I feel it is un-answerable.

Comment: I created a local copy of the site as you suggested. I then disabled **EVERY** module except the menu module, and the problem is still there. After I disabled the menu module, the issue is gone (but obviously I can't edit menus then).
So, it must be an issue in the Drupal core. I'll try to update the core now.

Comment: I am now close to giving it up... :(
I updated my local copy to core version 6.26 (the latest), then updated all modules that have updates (13 of them), then emptied cache and rebuilt permissions. **The problem still occurs...**
What on Earth could I still try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved.

Looks like that with the large menu tree, Mysql packet size was exceeded.

I just added the following to mysql config (my.ini) and the issue resolved:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```